# Getting list of object names in module with template haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'd like to be able to take a file with declarations such as:

```
test_1 = assert $ 1 == 1
test_2 = assert $ 2 == 1
```

and generate a basic run function like

```
main = runTests [test_1, test2]
```

The goal is to get something like Python's nosetest.

Can I do this with template Haskell? I cannot find a lot of documentation on it (there are many broken links in the Wiki).

Comment: What do you need Template Haskell for here?  `runTests` is a perfectly ordinary function; is the idea to be able to write `$(runTestsInModule "My.Module")` and have that produce `runTests [test_1, test_2, ...]`?

Comment: Yes! Is runTestsInModule a function that exists or do I need to write it? If not, that's the function that I want to know how to write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look into the [test-framework](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/test-framework) family of packages. In particular, the [test-framework-th](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/test-framework-th) package provides the Template Haskell function `defaultMainGenerator` which does exactly what you want for both QuickCheck and HUnit tests, as long as you follow the convention of prefixing HUnit test cases with `case_` and QuickCheck properties with `prop_`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Test.Framework.Providers.HUnit
import Test.Framework.Providers.QuickCheck2
import Test.Framework.TH

import Test.HUnit
import Test.QuickCheck

main = $(defaultMainGenerator)

case_checkThatHUnitWorks =
    assert $ 1 == 1

prop_checkThatQuickCheckWorks =
    (1 == 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

There is another way, you don't have to use template haskell.  [haskell-src-exts](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts) can parse Haskell, and you could extract from that.

Or if your purpose is practical, you can make like `quickcheck` and do a simple-minded parse, i.e. looking for identifiers that start with `prop_` in column 0.  This is a perfectly adequate solution for real work, though it may be theoretically unsatisfying.

Comment: Thanks. My goal's purely practical. I keep writing unit tests and then forgetting to add them to the list of tests to run, so I was looking to automate that.